# How to know call has been made from my application in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, call, openurl

I am new to iOS so pardon me when i make mistake. i want call a person from my application and i wrote these code for that :-

```
- (IBAction)onClickCallIcon:(id)sender {
    NSString *phoneNumber =_lblLeadMobileNumber.text;
    NSURL *phoneUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[@"telprompt://" stringByAppendingString:phoneNumber]];
    NSURL *phoneFallbackUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[@"tel://" stringByAppendingString:phoneNumber]];

    if ([UIApplication.sharedApplication canOpenURL:phoneUrl]){
        [UIApplication.sharedApplication openURL:phoneUrl];
    } else if ([UIApplication.sharedApplication canOpenURL:phoneFallbackUrl]){
        [UIApplication.sharedApplication openURL:phoneFallbackUrl];
    } 
}
```

and i want to know, Is call has been made or not? if possible how much length of call. how can achieve it?

Comment: then use callkit framework for your concept

Comment: @Anbu.karthik can i at least know the user has clicked call action on popup(alert) appeared or user clicked on cancel?

Comment: there is no public method available for this , if you want to handle then use `applicationDidEnterBackground`

Comment: @Anbu.karthik But you'll never know if the user triggered the call, or just switched to some other app. Short answer: You cannot do this, due to system immanent restrictions (privacy protection)

Comment: @Anbu.karthik the application didn't enter background when i am calling through these method.

Comment: @shreeRam - check resignactive is called

Comment: @Anbu.karthik yes it enter but enter when application enter background also.

Comment: @shreeRam - take only resignactive and wait i will update the answer

Comment: @shreeRam - check the updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Anbu.karthik & @Rocky for helping me.
i used allKit/CXCallObserver to observe the call  which is the answer of second part of my question and from that part i also get answer of first i.e call is connected or not. by using following code:-

**In viewdidload:**

```
CXCallObserver *callObserver = [[CXCallObserver alloc] init];
        [callObserver setDelegate:self queue:nil];
        self.callObserver = callObserver;
```

**and a method:**

```
- (void)callObserver:(CXCallObserver *)callObserver callChanged:(CXCall *)call {


    if (call.isOutgoing == YES && call.hasConnected == NO) {
        NSLog(@"CXCallState : Dialing");
    }

    if (call.isOutgoing == NO  && call.hasConnected == NO && call.hasEnded == NO && call != nil) {
        NSLog(@"CXCallState : Incoming");
    }

    if (call.hasConnected == YES && call.hasEnded == NO) {
        NSLog(@"CXCallState : Connected");
        startDate = [NSDate date];
    }
    if (call.hasConnected == YES && call.hasEnded == YES){
        NSLog(@"********** voice call disconnected **********/n");
        endDate = [NSDate date];
        NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components: NSCalendarUnitSecond
                                                                       fromDate: startDate toDate: endDate options: 0];
        NSInteger second = [components second];
        NSLog(@"call duration == %ld",(long)second);
        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        formatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
        [formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"];
        NSString *startDateFormatted = [formatter stringFromDate: startDate];
        NSString *endDateFormatted = [formatter stringFromDate: endDate];
        NSMutableDictionary *Dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [Dict setValue:startDateFormatted forKey:@"startDate"];
        [Dict setValue:endDateFormatted forKey:@"endDate"];
        [Dict setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)second] forKey:@"interval"];
        [currentShowingData updateCommunications:Dict];
    }
```

these give me all what i wanted. thanks again who helped me.

Answer (score 0):

You can make Call by:

- tel:// try to call direct the phone number
- telprompt:// shows you an alert to confirm call

if you want to know the user press `Call` button or `Cancel` button then can use `completionHandler` `status` for it.

**Swift Code**:

```
let phoneNumber = "XXXXXXXXXX" // Your phone number here
        if let url = URL(string: "tel://\(phoneNumber)") {
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: { (status) in
                    if status{
                        print("User Press Call Button")
                    }else{
                        print("User Press Cancel Button")
                    }
                })
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
            }
        }
```

**Objective-C Code**

```
    NSString *phoneNumber = @"XXXXXXXXXX";
    NSURL *phoneUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[@"tel://" stringByAppendingString:phoneNumber]];
    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary new];
    if ([UIApplication.sharedApplication canOpenURL:phoneUrl])
    {
        [UIApplication.sharedApplication openURL:phoneUrl options:options completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
            if (success){
                NSLog(@"User Press Call Button");
            }else{
                NSLog(@"User Press Cancel Button");
            }
        }];
    }
```

For your another question "**possible how much length of call**", the answer is **NO**, You can't get Call duration, there is no public API for this.
Refer Screenshot with running code:

[image]

Find [Attached](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q5fwplvizzpd6v5/TestCall.zip?dl=0) Running Project

Comment: status is  always Yes/True without pressing  call or cancel.

Comment: @shreeRam `completionHandler` is always work after take any action on prompt, then how you can dismiss the prompt without any action.

Comment: the value of success is Yes when it is just popup and it remain Yes.

Comment: @shreeRam copy the above Objective-C code and paste into your method onClickCallIcon, then run it. Refer running code Screenshot in updated answer.

Comment: Yes, i can see that but in my case status  is yes without even getting input from user.

Comment: @shreeRam running project file attached, download and run on Device.

Comment: yes, i downloaded that and when i run that in my testing device 6s(iOS 11.2.5) status is yes even before selecting call or cancel. Anyways thanks.