# Obj-C - Call number on button tap crashes app?

Tags: ios, objective-c

When my user taps a button, I want the app to prompt the user to make a call. I'm trying to accomplish this with the below, but whenever the button is tapped, the app crashes. I've double checked that NSString is populated inside phoneUrl as well (no null values). Any idea why this might be happening?

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSURL length]: unrecognized
> selector sent to instance 0x280244620' terminating with uncaught
> exception of type NSException

**ViewController.m**

```
- (IBAction)phoneLocation:(id)sender {
    
    NSString *number = self.locationHours.text;
    
    NSString *noDashes = [number
       stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];

    NSURL *phoneUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://%@", noDashes]];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneUrl]];

 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm surprised that even compiles. Pretty sure you might have a *warning* in your last line:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneUrl]];
```

Your `phoneUrl` is defined as a `NSURL *` prior to this call, but you are passing it as `NSString *` argument . You can verify this against Apple doc https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl/1572047-urlwithstring

> - (instancetype)URLWithString:(NSString *)URLString;

As a result inside `(instancetype)URLWithString:(NSString *)URLString;` the call (due to its internal implementation details) attempts to send `length` Objective-c runtime message (i.e. call `length` method from high level perspective) which would be perfectly valid for a `NSString *` but it's definitely not for `NSURL *`. Hence you see the `NSInvalidArgumentException` message you have provided.

A possible fix might be changing your last line to:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:phoneUrl];
```

even better as @OlSen suggested use the modern non deprecated API:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48618644/1443038

Comment: @Brittany  `API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("openURL:options:completionHandler:", ios(2.0, 10.0)) NS_EXTENSION_UNAVAILABLE_IOS("")` go this way.. [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48618644/1443038)

Comment: ...clearly I need to get some sleep, haha so obvious O_O no idea how I overlooked that. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

This answer builds basically on [Kamil.S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5329717/kamil-s)'s principle but with the modern API and it will not open phoneUrl at all if it is misspelled. It also prevents double typed `+` signs in phone numbers.

while researching how to make a phone call properly found only error prone phone number detections also tried to make a better detection without third party dependencies. (Beware the following solution is not meant to scan whole text with possibly a lot of numbers spread between words)
PS: but yes you could even hide a tel number in a larger string when the sorting of the numbers make sense. Assume you have a `NSString *dirty;` that contains..

`@"uglyPreString +49(17)-12-+345-678 uglyPostString seePlusInBetween?"`
or `@"tel://+49(17)-12-+345-678"`

Will it work?
Decided to write one that makes sure you have a correct dial-able number before you send a phone number around to invoke other apps (i.e. phone app).

```
NSString *dirty = @"uglyPreString +49(017)-12-+345-678 uglyPostString seePlusInBetween?";

// Let's keep all (only) possible phone number parts with a regex.
dirty = [dirty stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[^0-9,^+]" withString:@"" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, dirty.length)];

// We may have doublet '+' sign in there 
// ending up in a wrong call, prevent that
if (dirty.length>1) {
    // If the possible string contains '+' twice, kick out all '+' after first.
    // If there was no + sign at all, string stays as is. And
    // do not exceed max character index = NSMakeRange(1, dirty.length-1)
    dirty = [dirty stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[+]" withString:@"" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch range:NSMakeRange(1, dirty.length-1)];
    NSLog(@"does it look nice here? phone: %@",dirty);
}

// make sure it will not validate if detector doesnt agree its a phonenumber
// we don't want phonenumbers to fly as url call between app without users consent
// only apps that conform to handle @"tel://" protocol should be able to handle your call.
// so we set phonenumber invalid first.
NSString *phonenumber = nil;

NSError *error = nil;
NSDataDetector *detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypePhoneNumber error:&error];
NSArray *check = [detector matchesInString:dirty options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, dirty.length)];
if (check) {
    for (NSTextCheckingResult *result in check) {
        phonenumber = [result phoneNumber];
        if (phonenumber) break;
    }
    // if this part is reached, there is no valid phonenumber in dirty
}
    
if (phonenumber) {
    // construct the phone url
    NSString *dial = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://%@",phonenumber];
    NSURL *phoneUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:dial];
    NSLog(@"dial will be %@",phoneUrl.absoluteString);
    
    if ([UIApplication.sharedApplication canOpenURL:phoneUrl]) {
        [UIApplication.sharedApplication openURL:phoneUrl options:@{} completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
            // assuming the app that opens is phone app.
            NSLog(@"pressed %@ button", success ? @"green/call" : @"red/cancel");
        }];
    }
}
```